# Any way to print out Nagios Service UP Time Percentage?

Tags: php, monitoring, nagios

Is there anyway to print out Nagios Service/Host UP Time Percentage? e.g. PHP Class, Command Line Tools or ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Curl to fetch the Nagios CGIs content and [PHP DomDocument Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to fetch the uptime.

Answer (score 2):

Use Nagios::Report Perl module for generating report on percentage total time service OK http://metacpan.org/pod/Nagios::Report

Comment: Thank you, I've used this before, but Nagios::Report produces a full report. Is there anyway to get the exact value?

Comment: Similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281396/how-to-print-out-nagios-service-up-time-percentage-from-nagios-report-perl-modul/14291579#14291579

Comment: That question is about using Nagios::Report to get exact value, but this is about Any way to print out Nagios Service UP Time Percentage.

Answer (score 2):

Refer This `Perl` script:

https://github.com/MangeshBiradar/Check_mk/blob/master/nagios_report.pl

Hope This could answer your question.